# Lost system upgrade on factory reset

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, lg

I own a LG G Pro Lite which came with default android version 4.4.2 (Kitkat)

sometime back, it was upgraded to lollypop and was working fine.

Recently I had to reset the phone to restore factory settings which rolled back the upgrade.

In software update section, it is saying "Not updated yet" but when I try to upgrade the OS It is saying "You are using the latest software version for current OS."
What is causing this issue and how can I upgrade to latest android version?

Comment: If you do the factory reset the only data/settings in your phone will be deleted. Are you sure factory resetting downgraded to kitkat?

Comment: that is what I expected. but unfortunately it did downgrade the OS in my case.